# Why does pylance complain about protocol `protocol "Collection[Unknown]"` when using matplotlib LineCollection?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pylance

I am using `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` to plot a bunch of curves with an offset. Something like this:

```py
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = [np.cos(x), np.cos(x), np.cos(x), np.cos(x), np.cos(x)]
offs = 2
segs = [np.column_stack([x, index*offs + curve]) for index, curve in enumerate(y)]
line_segments = LineCollection(segs,
            colors=['r','0'])
ax.add_collection(line_segments)
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1 + offs*len(y))
plt.show()
```

which plots fine but my linter (pylance) complains about using `ax.add_collection` with `LineCollection`:

[image: screenshot of linter complaint]

My question is: why?

- is this a bug with `matplotlib.collections` (my suspicion)?
- should I have called `LineCollection` differently?
- is this an issue with the linter?
- something else?